# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user in cPanel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have uploaded a Laravel project in my cPanel. It gives the following error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'amartuki_finance'@'localhost' to database 'amartuki_finance'

But I have change my `.env` file's db name,user and password. Also configure in `config/database.php` file.

**`.env` file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=amartuki_finance
DB_USERNAME=amartuki_finance
DB_PASSWORD=amartuki_finance
```

**`config/database.php` file**

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'amartuki_finance'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'amartuki_finance'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'amartuki_finance'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

What's the solution then ! Anybody help please ?

Comment: make sure you added values are valid one... it seems `amartuki_finance` not allow to access the datebase `amartuki_finance`

assign the user to the database in cpanel.

Comment: I have change `amrtuki_financeUser` before posting here... Same error

Comment: Why the negative marking !!! will anyone explain please !!

Answer (score 5):

Solved my problem. It's a very silly mistake.

After creating user I didn't add the user to my database and that's why user didn't get any privilege.

Now change those things and the project run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow following method to load `env` values in `Laravel`

1. load env file

> Dotenv::load(base_path()); // path of your env file

2. require your values

> Dotenv::required(array('DB_PORT','DB_HOST',
>   'DB_DATABASE','DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD','DB_SOCKET'));

3. assign like below

> ```
> 'mysql' => [
>     'driver' => 'mysql',
>     'host' => getenv('DB_HOST'),
>     'port' => getenv('DB_PORT'),
>     'database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE'),
>     'username' => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
>     'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
>     'unix_socket' => getenv('DB_SOCKET'),
>     'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
>     'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
>     'prefix' => '',
>     'strict' => false,
>     'engine' => null,
> ],
> ```